# popupwindow display after animation finished

Tags: android

> In my project I've Right to Left animation on RelativeLayout,after finishing that,
>   At the same location I needed the Popupdropdown.Both animation & dropdown working good
>   but not in one after one.please guide me how to do.Thanks in advance.

```
scroll_bar_animation.setAnimation(animation_right_left);
scroll_bar_animation.startAnimation(animation_right_left);
location = new int[2];
scroll_bar_animation.getLocationOnScreen(location);
p = new Point();
p.x = location[0];
p.y = location[1];
final View v = upper_scrollbar;

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
low_scrollbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);//This is to be disappear after animation so
more_Info_Popup.showPopup(p, v, p.x);//This is the popup window and implemented in
an other class
}
}, 400L);
```

Comment: Is your issue that the popup window appears when the animation starts, not afterwards?

Comment: hi,Thanks for attempting,after animation finished,drop down popupwindow will begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add AnimationListener to your scroll_bar_animation instance, and show the popup when it ends, inside this method:

```
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
  {...}
```

Please see the reference of this listener here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html

A few links that may help you understanding how AnimationListeners work, with examples:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/animation-resources-and-animationlistener.html

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/09/handle-animation-event.html?m=1

http://www.androidadb.com/class/an/AnimationListener.html

Answer (score 0):

> First we have to create the instance of Animation Class

```
Animation animation_right_left = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.reverse_left);
animation_right_left.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
.....implement the unimplemented methods  }
```